# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.span.model.Customer.custName

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been working with my pet project, with angular, springboot and Hibernate. I am pretty new to hibernate. I have been getting the following exception.

> 2019-01-31 20:29:27.973 ERROR 5256 --- [nio-8900-exec-1]
>   o.h.p.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl        : HHH000122:
>   IllegalArgumentException in class: com.span.model.Customer, getter
>   method of property: custName 2019-01-31 20:29:27.973  INFO 5256 ---
>   [nio-8900-exec-1] c.s.s.daoService.CommonServiceDaoImpl    : Exception
>   in saveCustomer: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException:
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of
>   com.span.model.Customer.custName
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred calling getter of com.span.model.Customer.custName   at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.getForInsert(GetterMethodImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:559)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:225)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4999)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:271)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)     at
>   com.span.service.daoService.CommonServiceDaoImpl.saveCustomer(CommonServiceDaoImpl.java:27)
>     at
>   com.span.service.daoService.CommonServiceDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cde5bb03.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   com.span.service.daoService.CommonServiceDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9118af.saveCustomer()
>     at
>   com.span.service.RegisterServiceImpl.registerCustomer(RegisterServiceImpl.java:18)
>     at
>   com.span.controller.HomeController.registerCustomer(HomeController.java:27)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of
>   declaring class   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:42)
>     ... 89 more 2019-01-31 20:29:27.992  INFO 5256 --- [nio-8900-exec-1]
>   c.s.s.daoService.CommonServiceDaoImpl    : saveCustomer ends with
>   customerId: 0

My method saveCustomer in CommonServiceDaoImpl looks like this:

```java
public int saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
  log.info("saveCustomer starts");
  try {
    customer.setCustAge(util.calculateAge(customer.getCustDob()));
    customer.setCustPass(util.getSHA(customer.getCustPass()));
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new     
    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(customer); 
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();        
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    log.info("Exception in saveCustomer: "+ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
    log.info("saveCustomer ends with customerId: "+customer.getCustId());
    return customer.getCustId();
  }
```

The customer model class looks like the following:

```java
package com.span.model;

import java.util.Date;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;

@Data
 public class Customer {

    private int custId;
    private String custName;
    private int custAge;
    private String custGen;
    private Date custDob;
    private String custEmail;
    private String custMob;
    private String custPass;
}
```

The controller call is as following:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/brw/registerCustomer", method = {RequestMethod.POST })
public Long registerCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
    int custId = 0;
    log.info("registerCustomer starts..." + customer);
    try {
        custId = registerService.registerCustomer(customer);
        log.info("registerCustomer ends..." + custId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception is: " + ex);
        log.info("Exception is: " + ex);
    }
    return Long.valueOf(custId);
}
```

Finally my hibernate mapping looks following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.span.model.Customer" table="Customer">

        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the customer detail.</meta>
        <id name="custId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="cust_id">
            <generator class="sequence-identity">
                <param name="sequence">customer_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="custName" type="string" column="cust_name" />
        <property name="custAge" column="cust_age" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <property name="custGen" column="cust_gen" type="string" />
        <property name="custEmail" column="cust_mail" type="string" />
        <property name="custMob" column="cust_mob" type="string" />
        <property name="custPass" column="password" type="string" />
        <property name="custDob" column="cust_dob" type="java.sql.Date" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am using oracle 12g.
Please let me know where I am mistaken, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have the getters and setters in place in the customer class. Can you post the getter of the CustName ?  Initialy I thought it is configured for property access and it does not have the getters and setter, but now I see y9u have them based on the usage of the entity.

Comment: yes I am using @Data annotation frm lombok which generates getters and setters automatically